# How to create array comprehension in Julia with two dimentions

Tags: arrays, julia, list-comprehension

I'm new to Julia, and I wanted to learn how to do an array comprehension. I have this lines of code:

```
for i in 1:m
    for j in 1:n
        arr[i, j] = i + j
    end
end
```

I want to do the same thing with an array comprehension. I wrote this the below code, but I know this is not an array comprehension. Please help me create an array comprehension.

```
for i in 1:m, j in 1:n
    arr[i, j] = i + j
end
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more Julian way of filling the array would be this (of course, I'm using an array comprehension):

```
arr = [i + j for i in 1:m, j in 1:n]
```

Answer (score 2):

your code has a little typo:

```
for i in 1:m, j in 1:n #Julia loops can iterate over multiple indices at once
    arr[i, j] = i + j
end
```

but that is not a comprehension, is just a regular for loop.

Comment: I think OP is asking for an array comprehension.

Comment: yes, it does, and your answer is the correct one. but he has a typo on his attempt on a comprehension, and i want to point out that his syntax was (almost) correct too